# Changing NavigationView.MenuItemsSource crashes

Tags: uwp-xaml

I need to change the `NavigationView` menu depending on the page I navigate to.

```
<ux:NavigationView x:Name="NavView" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind MainMenu, Mode=OneWay}">
```

`MainMenu` is a dependency property of type `List<ux.NavigationViewItemBase>`. Everything is still fine when I fill it in my constructor:

```
MainMenu = GetMenuItems().ToList();
```

But when I try to change it later:

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(item.PageType, null, transitionInfo);
MainMenu = GetMenuItems().ToList();
```

my app crashes with *0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.* in `NavigationView.cpp` at line 924.

Is it completely forbidden to change the menu items later or did I hit another problem somehow?

Comment: Is your app a UWP app? If it is a UWP app, could you please share an [mcve] on GitHub or OneDrive? I could not reproduce the issue with the code you post.

Comment: Yes. I'll post. In the meantime, I realised this is a Microsoft.UI.Xaml issue (2.5.0-prerelease.201027002). I need the package because I don't want to limit my support to just the latest W10 versions and I needed the prerelease because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073268/disabled-color-of-numbox-header

Comment: To be found at https://github.com/deakjahn/MenuCrash .

Comment: OK, it seems to work if I don't use the Microsoft.UI.Xaml for the navigation. But there's one thing the documentation isn't clear about. Can I still target Fall Creator as a minimum if I use the NuGet package but I don't refer to it other than merge its resources and only refer to it directly when really necessary (NumberBox)? NavViews and everything else left untouched? Will this support it back to Fall or do I have to give up and only support the newer minimum target?

Comment: It should work only using the NumberBox control from Microsoft.UI.Xaml Nuget Package. As the issue only related to the NavigationView control from the Nuget package.